# Add custom post type template via plugin

Tags: wordpress, post

I'm creating a plugin for a custom post type. I want to add a custom template for it. But I'm not sure how to add it via the plugin.

How can I add a custom post type template via the plugin?

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

You can simply create and assign custom page templates for your custom post type in your custom plugin.

Just create 2 template file - **single-{post_type}.php** and **archive-{post_type}.php** - in a new **templates** sub-directory of your plugin directory.

Then add some code as per below example in your main plugin:

```
/*
 * Set Page templates for CPT "your_cpt"
 */


add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_plugin_templates' );
function my_plugin_templates( $template ) {

    $post_type = 'your_cpt'; // Change this to the name of your custom post type!

    if ( is_post_type_archive( $post_type ) && file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . "templates/archive-$post_type.php" ) ){
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . "templates/archive-$post_type.php";
    }

    if ( is_singular( $post_type ) && file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . "templates/single-$post_type.php" ) ){
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . "templates/single-$post_type.php";
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Hope this example would be helpful for you.
Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

Below is a complete (blank) plugin that I put together based on my previously posted answer. I loaded it in my theme (based on twentyfifteen) and it works. Together with the plugin, as-is, you would also need The following file structure

```
 - schs-blank/css schs-blank/js schs-blank/images
   schs-blank/archive-blank.php schs-blank/single-blank.php
   schs-blank/schs-blank-edit-posts.php
   schs-blank/schs-blank-template.php
```

It should not be too tricky to figure out what should be in the above files, but for starters just put "`<h1>{filename}</h1>`" to see where each page is called.

```
<?php
/*
        Plugin Name: SCHS Blank Plugin
        Plugin URI: http://www.southcoasthosting.com/schs-blank
        Tags: jquery, flyout, vertical, menu, animated, css, navigation, widget, plugin, scroll
        Description: Creates a widget to place a vertical menu which caters for many menu items.
        Author: Gavin Simpson
        Version: 0.1
        Author URI: http://www.southcoasthosting.com
        074 355 1881
*/
class schs_blank
{
    protected $plugin_slug;
    private static $instance;
    protected $templates;

    public static function get_instance() 
    {
        if( null == self::$instance )
        {
            self::$instance = new schs_blank();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    } 
    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->templates = array();
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/schs-blank-template.php';
        $this->templates = array('schs-blank-template.php' => 'SCHS Blank Page Template','schs-blank-edit-posts.php'=>'Edit Blank Post Template');
        if(!is_admin())
        {
            add_action( 'wp_blank', array('schs_blank', 'header') );
        }
        else
            add_action( 'wp_blank', array('schs_blank', 'footer') );

        add_filter('page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args',array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ));
        add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ));
        add_filter( 'template_include', array($this,'schs_force_template' ));
        add_filter('template_include', array( $this, 'view_project_template') );

        add_action('admin_menu', array($this,'setup_blank_admin_menus'));
        add_action( 'init', array($this,'blank_custom_post' ));
    }
    function schs_force_template($template)
    {
        if( is_archive( 'blank' ) )
        {
            $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/'. plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__) ) .'/archive-blank.php';
        }
        if( is_singular( 'blank' ) ) 
        {
            $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/'. plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__) ) .'/single-blank.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
    function header(){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'blank-css', schs_blank::get_plugin_directory() . "/css/blank.css" );
        wp_enqueue_script('schs_blank', schs_blank::get_plugin_directory() . '/js/schs-blank.js', array('jquery'));
    }
    function footer()
    {
    }
    function get_plugin_directory(){
        return WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/schs-blank';   
    }
    function setup_blank_admin_menus()
    {
        add_menu_page('SCHS Blank Settings', 'SCHS Blank Settings', 'manage_options', 
            'SCHS_blank_settings', array($this,'SCHS_page_settings'));
        add_submenu_page('SCHS_blank_settings', 
            'SCHS Page Elements', 'Blank Topics', 'manage_options', 
            'SCHS_blank_topics_settings', array($this,'SCHS_blank_topics_settings')); 
    }
    function SCHS_page_settings()
    {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
        <h2>There are no Blank options at this stage.</h2>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    function SCHS_blank_topics_settings()
    {
        ?>
        <div id="blank_topics" class="wrap">
        <h1>There are no blank topics at this stage</h1>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    function blank_custom_post()
    {
        $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Blank', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Topic', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Blank Topic' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Blank Topic' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Blank Topic' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Blank Topics' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Blank Topics' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Blank Topics' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No blank topics found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No blank topics found in the trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Blank'
        );
        $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our blank topic specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor'),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'menu_icon'     => $this->get_plugin_directory().'/images/blank-icon.png',
        );
        register_post_type( 'blank', $args );
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    public function register_project_templates( $atts )
    {
                // Create the key used for the themes cache
                $cache_key = 'page_templates-' . md5( get_theme_root() . '/' . get_stylesheet() );
                // Retrieve the cache list. 
                // If it doesn't exist, or it's empty prepare an array
                $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
                if ( empty( $templates ) ) {
                        $templates = array();
                } 
                // New cache, therefore remove the old one
                wp_cache_delete( $cache_key , 'themes');
                // Now add our template to the list of templates by merging our templates
                // with the existing templates array from the cache.
                $templates = array_merge( $templates, $this->templates );
                // Add the modified cache to allow WordPress to pick it up for listing
                // available templates
                wp_cache_add( $cache_key, $templates, 'themes', 1800 );
                return $atts;
    }

    /**
         * Checks if the template is assigned to the page
         */
    public function view_project_template( $template )
    {
                global $post;
                if (!isset($this->templates[get_post_meta( 
                    $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true 
                )] ) ) {

                        return $template;

                } 
                $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). get_post_meta( 
                    $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true 
                );
                // Just to be safe, we check if the file exist first
                if( file_exists( $file ) )
                {
                    return $file;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo $file; 
                    exit;
                }
                return $template;
    }

}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'schs_blank', 'get_instance' ) );
?>
```

I hope this helps a bit more.

Comment: in the function 'schs_force_template' did you change the 'forum' to whatever your custom type is named?

Comment: Yes, I did. I changed it to "smartphone" which is my post type

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the function to add the custom type, just to make sure it matches what you have. Again you will have to change 'forum' to 'smartphone'. Where I have '$this->get_plugin_directory()' you will have to add your plugins folder.

Comment: First off all, thanks for your help. Now, I'm getting the error  `unexpected public (T_PUBLIC)` I've removed `public` but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: I used http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/ and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/create-custom-page-templates-with-plugins to come up with the above code. Perhaps look at these pages and see if it help you find where things are going wrong.

Comment: I have posted new code in my answer, which works on the theme I am currently working on. Try it,.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, kindly try it, Thanks
Templates is loaded into cpt file, which was located at
custom_plugin -> app -> cpt -> cpt_article.php
Template is located
custom_plugin -> app -> templates

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'load_my_custom_template', 99, 1 );
 function load_custom_templates($single_template) {
   global $post;
   if ($post->post_type == 'article' ) {
   $single_template = trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .'app/templates' ).'single_article.php';
  }
   return $single_template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You create a template file in your plugin, e.g /templates/myposttype-page.php
- Then add below code into your plugin.
- Change 'myposttype' to your post type

```
$custom_post_type = 'myposttype';
add_filter("theme_{$custom_post_type}_templates", "add_{$custom_post_type}_template");

add_filter('single_template', "redirect_{$custom_post_type}_template");

function add_myposttype_template() {

     $templates['myposttype-page.php'] = 'My type Template';
    
     return $templates;
}

function redirect_myposttype_template ($template) {

      if( is_page_template('myposttype-page.php') ){
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'templates/myposttype-page.php';
      }

      return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add single and archive files in your custom plugin

```
  add_filter( 'template_include', 'your_templates' );
function your_templates( $template ) {

    $post_type = 'cpt'; // Change this to the name of your custom post type!
    echo plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "templates/single-" . $post_type . ".php";
    if ( is_post_type_archive( $post_type ) && file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "templates/archive-" . $post_type . ".php" ) ){
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "templates/archive-" . $post_type . ".php";
    }

    if ( is_singular( $post_type ) && file_exists( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "templates/single-" . $post_type . ".php" ) ){
        $template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "templates/single-" . $post_type . ".php";
    }

    return $template;
}
```